# Suspend JamVM and Restart It?

Tags: c, jvm, posix, jamvm

I am working on JamVM, a popular small Java VM, and I would like to stop it (suspend all the threads), execute a function within the VM (a C function) and then restart all the threads.

I tried to handle a signal (Ctrl-C), execute my function, but this didn't work, because every signal the VM receives, it transmits it to the running java program...

So do you have a way to stop a VM, and then restart it? (with or without signals, it doesn't matter)